# JS - Canvas from image file - works only with browser cache present

Tags: javascript

My JS code draws image on canvas, using image file. However, this code works only with browser cache present - when page is loaded second time. With empty cache (ctrl +f5), canvas is empty. Is there any way to preload image file before code is executed or some other way to make it work for first time?

```
<canvas id="nr"></canvas>

<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('nr').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.src = 'tlo.jpg';

var width = img.naturalWidth;
var height = img.naturalHeight;

document.getElementById('nr').width = width;
document.getElementById('nr').height = height;

console.log(width); //prints 0 with cache empty

ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Image loading is an asynchronous operation so one waits for the image to be loaded before copying to the canvas. Try something like:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('nr').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.src = 'tlo.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
   var width = img.naturalWidth;
   var height = img.naturalHeight;

   document.getElementById('nr').width = width;
   document.getElementById('nr').height = height;

   console.log(width); //prints 0 with cache empty

   ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
}
```

You could register an event listener on the `img` element if you prefer.

---

I would also recommend wrapping the entire code block in a function to be executed after the window load event has fired. Modifying DOM elements during the page loading process may work, in your browser, at this time, but comes with no guarantee of success in general.

Comment: I use http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/ for this and it works fantastically well, makes canvas code very easy to reason about.